# Working on Python Homework, Having Trouble With Loop

Tags: python

I'm currently in a beginner's Python course at my university. Part of my homework is to create a program that resembles the famous children's song 99 Bottles of Pop. The task is:

1. The user inputs an item.
2. The program prints out a statement as such: "x bottles of pop on the wall, x bottles of pop. Take one down, pass it around, (x-1) bottles of pop on the wall" until it reaches 0.
   Once it reaches 0, the program must stop and say that there are no bottles of pop on the wall.
3. The limit is 99. If a user inputs anything above 99, display an error and force the counter to begin at 99.

Makes sense right? So, here is my code:

```
#Bottles of Pop on the Wall
#User inputs a number to start with
#Program returns with singing the popular song down to 0
#

print("Bottles of Pop on the Wall Program")

userBottle = int(input("How many bottles? "))
bottleCount = userBottle

while bottleCount > 1:
        newBottle = userBottle - 1
        bottleCount -= 1

    if bottleCount > 99:
        print("ALERT: no more than 99 bottles allowed, reverting to 99 bottles")

        userBottle = 99
        bottleCount = 99
        newBottle = 99


    print(userBottle , "bottles of pop on the wall, ", userBottle , "bottles of pop" ,
      "\ntake one down, pass it around, " , newBottle , "bottles of pop on the wall")
    userBottle -= 1

if bottleCount == 1:
    print(userBottle , "bottle of pop on the wall, ", userBottle , "bottle of pop" ,
      "\ntake one down, pass it around, " , "no bottles of pop on the wall")



input("\nThank you for playing! Press Enter to exit.")
```

So, if the user inputs any number below 100, the program works perfectly. However, if the user inputs anything above 99, that's where I run into problems.

What will happen is the loop will run down to 1, but will not end. It will repeat one last time, and it will return:

```
1 bottles of pop on the wall,  1 bottles of pop 
take one down, pass it around,  0 bottles of pop on the wall
0 bottle of pop on the wall,  0 bottle of pop 
take one down, pass it around,  no bottles of pop on the wall

Thank you for playing! Press Enter to exit.
```

Obviously this is incorrect. What is wrong with my loop so I can make sure this doesn't happen when a user enters a number bigger than 99?

Thank you so much and I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: It was bottles of beer when I was a kid...

Comment: If the count is >99 and `userBottle` becomes 99, then shouldn't the `newBottle` be 98?

Comment: To start with, I'd move the check for n>99 out of the loop. Once you've checked, it'll never be false again. I believe this also fixes your bug

Comment: You seem to be using 3 different variables to represent the number of bottles. That will be a good source of bugs

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an aliasing problem.

Outside the loop you ask the user to enter a number, say they enter 101, and then you set `bottleCount = userBottle`. Then inside the loop you reset the value of `userBottle` to 99. But observe the following:

```
In [6]: userBottle = 101

In [7]: bottleCount = userBottle

In [8]: userBottle = 99

In [9]: userBottle
Out[9]: 99

In [10]: bottleCount
Out[10]: 101
```

The following is as your program. You may have changed the userBottle value, but you have not changed the bottleCount value.

The thing to do would be to write a function to get the userBottle value in a controlled way, and the function just returns itslef, until the value is correct. An example might be:

```
def get_user_bottles(input_message, error_message1, error_message2):
    #This makes sure the user inputs a number
    try:
        userBottle = int(raw_input(input_message))
    except ValueError:
        print error_message1
        return get_user_bottles(input_message, error_message1, error_message2)
    #This makes sure the user inputs a number between 1 and 99
    if userBottle not in range(1, 100):
        print error_message2
        return get_user_bottles(input_message, error_message1, error_message2)
    else:
        return userBottle

userBottle = get_user_bottles('How many bottles?',
                              'The value must be an integer between 1 and 99',
                              'That value is out of bounds, it must be between 1 and 99')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use one variable to track the number of bottles

```
print("Bottles of Pop on the Wall Program")

bottle_count = int(input("How many bottles? "))

if bottle_count > 99:
    print("ALERT: no more than 99 bottles allowed, reverting to 99 bottles")
    bottle_count = 99

while bottle_count > 1:
    print(bottle_count , "bottles of pop on the wall, ", bottle_count , "bottles of pop")
    bottle_count -= 1
    print("take one down, pass it around, ", bottle_count, "bottles of pop on the wall")

print(bottle_count , "bottle of pop on the wall, ", bottle_count , "bottle of pop")
print("take one down, pass it around, no bottles of pop on the wall")

input("\nThank you for playing! Press Enter to exit.")
```

For the next step, you should use format strings and the `.format` method. eg.

```
print("{bottle_count} bottles of pop on the wall, "
      "{bottle_count} bottles of pop".format(bottle_count=bottle_count))
```

Comment: This is perfect! I had forgotten to mention that the exercise required that I used at least one "while" loop. Not only does this solve the bug, but this is so much more efficient than my own code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This avoids looping over bottles.  It uses list-comprehension instead:

```
n = int(input("How many bottles? "))
if n > 99:
    print("Sorry.  You cannot afford %s bottles.  Starting with 99." % n)
    n = 99
song = '\n'.join('%s bottles of pop on the wall,  %s bottles of pop\ntake one down, pass it around,  %s bottles of pop on the wall' % (i,i,i-1) for i in range(n, 0, -1))
print(song + "\nno bottles of pop on the wall,  no bottles of pop\n")
input("Thank you for playing! Press Enter to exit.")
```

Sample output:

```
How many bottles? 2
2 bottles of pop on the wall,  2 bottles of pop
take one down, pass it around,  1 bottles of pop on the wall
1 bottles of pop on the wall,  1 bottles of pop
take one down, pass it around,  0 bottles of pop on the wall
no bottles of pop on the wall,  no bottles of pop

Thank you for playing! Press Enter to exit.
```

I took the liberty of modifying the last line of the song.  After you have 0 bottles of pop, I didn't think it made sense to try to take another one down from the wall.  You can easily change it back if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change:
`if bottleCount == 1:`

to this:
`if userBottle == 1:` since this is the variable you decrement at each step.